# Why in rails CLI do I constantly see "←[32m.←[0m"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie trying to follow Michael Hartl's excellent rails tutorial. I have upgraded to rails 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3 which I run on windows vista. The problem occurs when I run certain command line functions such as rspec. eg

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/
←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m← [32m.←[0m
←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m
←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m←[32m.←[0m

Finished in 5.41 seconds
←[32m29 examples, 0 failures←[0m
```

I thought the problem might be related to it trying to show colours but I have tried running rspec with the --color tag and there is no difference (or any colour). I have also seen the problem in the rails console itself. Perhaps my machine is not set up to display certain characters correctly.

Any help would be gratefully received!

thanks

Answer (score 5):

They are terminal control characters, they can be used to change the colour of the terminal as suggested in the question and also to move the cursor and delete characters. If these appear with colour disabled then I would assume they are cursor movement control characters.

**EDIT:**

http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm lists the VT100 control characters. It appears that it *is* attempting to set the text color, to green.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how I can actually show green rather than have these odd characters everywhere?

Comment: It would depend on what platform you are running on. If you are running under windows these escape characters are ignored by the terminal. It not then it looks like the terminal either doesn't support these control codes (quite unlikely) or they are disabled somehow. Maybe due to having changed a setting somewhere in your terminal emulator. Something such as the Mac Terminal application or xterm or gnome-terminal under linux should support these. *Edit* just seen you are running vista and therefore the escapes are indeed ignored by the terminal. Colouring the win terminal is done differntly.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll see if I can figure out how to let it know its running on windows.

Comment: I have tried adding win32console ad ansicon functionality but still no colours. However I _have_ managed to get rid of the control codes by adding `--no-color`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387667/git-bash-is-displaying-strange-characters-on-windows-7 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301354/weird-control-characters-from-gradle-in-windows-10 for a bit more context

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the `.rspec` file in your application directory
2. remove the first line (`--color`)
3. Save, done :-)