# Strange characters in PHP Composer and Laravel installer output - Windows 10 CMD

Tags: cmd, composer-php, windows-10, phpstorm, ansicon

I have this problem on Windows 10 -- PHP Composer showing strange characters.

[image: php composer screenshot]

I have tried to install `ansicon` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387667/git-bash-is-displaying-strange-characters-on-windows-7) and it solved the problem but then if I try to use terminal in JetBrains PhpStorm it's crashing...

Maybe I need to fix it without that `ansicon` but I can't find how.

I have this problem only on my Laptop -- on my Desktop it's working perfectly fine. They both have Windows 10 and PHP + Composer at the latest versions.

Comment: Those are escape sequences -- usually used to represent color info in plain-text output. Try [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) program as your console/terminal replacement if you will not be able to make it work in native Windows 10 console.

Comment: Thanks but it's too complicated, with too many options.
I end up using bash on ubuntu on windows, working great!
[install bash on windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

Comment: I have the same problem, but it used to work correctly. Maybe the windows anniversary update broke some things?

Comment: @Cheshire you are right, apparently after the anniversary update on my desktop i got the problem too... but i'm using git bash or PowerShell so it's fine... don't need the old CMD anymore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, friend.

Have you tried PowerShell? Only if you didn't notice, but it is also available on Github now: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

[PHP Composer on PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzGfT.png)

I think the problem is that the common Windows terminal does not support the ANSI/VT100 colors.

Check this old thread:
[How to make win32 console recognize ANSI/VT100 escape sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences)

Hope this helps.