# when I running a command (composer) in the command prompt, it doesn't show me the proper green text command instead of showing me some garbage value

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

here is an example of the result:

> [32mComposer [39m version [33m1.1.3[39m 2016-06-26 15:42:08 
>       [33mUsage:[39m 
>         command[options][arguments]
>       [33mOptions:[39m
>       [32m-h, --help[39m  Display this help message

I am in the process of learning to install php Laravel and I get stuck here.
p/s: I've learn php for awhile and now I am trying to create a project in Laravel.Please help.

Comment: Write the command you're trying to run..

Comment: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5323 might help. Those "garbage values" are actually the color codes that aren't being properly interpreted.

Comment: I am running "composer" on command prompt

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange characters in PHP Composer and Laravel installer output - Windows 10 CMD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882176/strange-characters-in-php-composer-and-laravel-installer-output-windows-10-cmd)

Comment: windows @SteveBuzonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your terminal doesn't support ANSI color codes.  Run with `--no-ansi` so that you see clean pure text output.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add --no-ansi to the composer.bat file at

C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat

change the line to

php "%~dp0composer.phar" %* --no-ansi