# My php artisan have unrecognizable characters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I did't remember this problem before. 
Maybe it appeared recently. 
How to solve this?[image]

Comment: that's either a problem with artisan being encoded strangely so it can't output https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code correctly, or your terminal being unable to render them. in the first case file an issue with the developers; in the second case use something that's more intelligent than a typewriter as your terminal, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is color characters. Version looks green at my linux server.

Use `php artisan --version --no-ansi`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like color codes that are not shown correctly.

Go to console options >Terminal and switching from `xterm` (default) to `xterm-256color` fixed the issue.

Restart the console.

Comment: Where can I find the console options?

Comment: Right click on console and select Options.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the common Windows terminal does not support the `ANSI/VT100` colors.

I think you should try with [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell)

**OR**

Change the terminal options to "xterm-256 color". Right click in the terminal → options → terminal → change the type to xterm-256 color → restart terminal.

Comment: I right click the terminal, but didn't find the options.

Comment: @无名小路 Let me check

Comment: @无名小路 Please follow below links 

1. https://laravel.io/forum/09-28-2016-php-artisan-list-display-strange-characters

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882176/strange-characters-in-php-composer-and-laravel-installer-output-windows-10-cmd

Comment: I have downloaded PowerShell, how to use it to solve my problem?

Comment: @无名小路 sure i will tell you just a minute

Comment: @无名小路 I think all instruction given in the github