# Symfony console output creates extra unwanted characters

Tags: symfony, symfony5

i got this weird error, where every output in the console with symfony creates some extra characters. The following is the output after a basic `symfony` in the console.

```
$ symfony
←[32mSymfony CLI←[39m version ←[33mv4.22.0←[39m (c) 2017-2021 Symfony SAS
Symfony CLI helps developers manage projects, from local code to remote infrastructure

These are common commands used in various situations:

←[33mWork on a project locally←[39m

  ←[32mnew←[39m                                                            Create a new Symfony project
  ←[32mserve←[39m                                                          Run a local web server
  ←[32mserver:stop←[39m                                                    Stop the local web server
  ←[32msecurity:check←[39m                                                 Check security issues in project dependencies
  ←[32mcomposer←[39m                                                       Runs Composer without memory limit
  ←[32mconsole←[39m                                                        Runs the Symfony Console (bin/console) for current project
  ←[32mphp, pecl, pear, php-fpm, php-cgi, php-config, phpdbg, phpize←[39m  Runs the named binary using the configured PHP version

←[33mManage a project on Cloud←[39m

  ←[32mlogin←[39m        Log in with your SymfonyConnect account
  ←[32minit←[39m         Initialize a new project using templates
  ←[32mlink←[39m         Link current git repository to a SymfonyCloud project
  ←[32mprojects←[39m     List active projects
  ←[32menvs←[39m         List environments
  ←[32menv:create←[39m   Create an environment
  ←[32mtunnel:open←[39m  Open SSH tunnels to the app's services
  ←[32mssh←[39m          Open an SSH connection to the app container
  ←[32mdeploy←[39m       Deploy an environment
  ←[32mdomains←[39m      List domains
  ←[32mvars←[39m         List variables
  ←[32muser:add←[39m     Add a user to the project

Show all commands with ←[32msymfony.exe help←[39m,
Get help for a specific command with ←[32msymfony.exe help COMMAND←[39m.
```

As you can see, I get this `←[33m` here and there. Any help is gratefully accepted. Please let me know if you need any additional information from me.

```
$ bin/console --version
Symfony 5.2.1 (env: dev, debug: true)
```

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/740b2ac8337b2cf9ba889477b9dbb6466c2e2896

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387667/git-bash-is-displaying-strange-characters-on-windows-7