# Weird control characters from Gradle in Windows 10

Tags: windows, gradle, cmd, windows-10, windows-console

In the console I get "funky" output from Gradle when run from CMD since switching to Windows 10.

```
[0K
[0K
[2A[1m<==-----------> 18% EXECUTING [9s][m[34D[1B[1m> :compileScala[m[15D[1B[2A[1m<==-----------> 18% EXECUTING [10s][m[35D[2B[2A[1m<==-----------> 18% EXECUTING [11s][m[35D[2B[2A[1m<==-----------> 18% EXECUTING [12s][m[35D[2B[2A[1m<==-----------> 18% EXECUTING [13s][m[35D[2B[2A[1m<==-----------> 18% EXECUTING [14s][m[35D[2B[2Athere were four feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
four warnings found
```

I imagine this is some sort of control-characters-gone-wild where Gradle is trying to sensibly colour its output and Windows is interpreting that wrong. PowerShell and SBT works fine - but copying the console "Properties" settings from PowerShell to CMD doesn't fixit.

Has anyone resolved this?

**UPDATE 2018-01-28** It's also happening in my Jenkins/Alpine/Docker setup atop OSX/macOS/whatnot. Not just windows anymore.

... but ... it doesn't happen in the Surface laptop work gave me ... super weird. Whatevs `gradlew --console=plain` works fine for me.

Comment: CMD restores the original console mode when running an external program, which is technically the right thing to do. Apparently PowerShell doesn't do this, so the virtual terminal escapes should work if you start CMD from PowerShell -- until someone fixes this bug in PowerShell.

Comment: The main bug here is in Gradle. If it depends on virtual terminal support, then it should enable it in the console by getting the current mode via `GetConsoleMode`, then OR in the `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING` flag, and set the new mode via `SetConsoleMode`. If this operation fails then VT mode isn't supported. It's either an older version of Windows or the option to use the legacy console is set.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing you could pass `--console plain` in the gradle command line to disable the rich console which is likely the cause of the "funky" characters

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html

Comment: Gradle 2.6 in powershell under win 10 produces correct behavior but gradle 4.1 does not.

Comment: Yes, there's similar weirdness when I run Gradle through git bash on Windows. Gradle works fine in normal DOS terminal on Windows. As I said you can use `--console plain` to stop the special characters

Comment: it seems to work. output are much better but I won't be able to see the percentage %
using the export TERM=cygwin like Mark mentioned below seems to give a better results

Answer (score 43):

I've seen this happen in the Git BASH shell that's part of Git For Windows. For me, the solution was to set TERM to cygwin. This fixed the output without introducing any issues handling backspace.

```
export TERM=cygwin
```

I also tried xterm, xterm-256color, ansi, and vt100. The cygwin term has been the most reliable for me. I'm now running \usr\bin\bash.exe in Windows Terminal, and so far it has worked well.

Comment: That seems to work, though I don't get the logic of why a Windows Terminal environment needs a cygwin TERM. I guess one of the mysteries of cygwin kruft.

Comment: if you use git bash in windows. edit the file in git\etc\bash.bashrc
and add the line 
export TERM=cygwin
to the end of the file so you don't have to type this command everytime you run a terminal

Comment: @Ali suggestion above worked for me when I added it to the .bash_profile file in my windows home directory.

Comment: @xpusostomos it's probably trying to do this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: You can put this export statement in the `bash.bashrc` in the `Git/etc` installation folder
Mine was: `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\bash.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

To fix this on Windows 10 create a new `DWORD` key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\VirtualTerminalLevel` set to `1`.  See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/413073/windows-console-with-ansi-colors-handling/1050078#1050078) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same problem when using [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/pl-pl/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701) and "Git Bash" profile added automatically by GIT installer. For me the solution was to change the command-line for starting the terminal from `<git_install_path>/bin/bash.exe` to `<git_install_path>/bin/usr/bash.exe` following [this advice](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13279#issuecomment-714222063).

Answer (score 0):

like @lance-java said the ANSI output can be disabled throw the command line option --console

```
./gradle bootRun --console plain
```

or

```
./gradle bootRun --console=plain
```

another way is to set the property in the gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.console=plain
```

see documentation:   [Gradle configuration properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me was to just update Git Bash: `git update-git-for-windows`

Comment: from what version to what version?